# Is it possible to change the way a form loads with different data fields and values (Acces 2010)

Tags: forms, ms-access, rows

I have Access 2010. I was wondering if there is a way to get the form to load different for every selection.
Example
Item A has 10 Rows and 6 columns of filled in data
Item B has 3 Rows and 2 Columns of filled in data
Both are from the same table.
Is there a way when a certain item is selected from a drop down menu to load, without having multiple forms, only the filled in data? Output would resemble Excel format.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- Creating dynamically-generated form structure in MSFT Access can be done with sub-forms.

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- MSFT Access
- Creating forms

#### Problem

- **Scenario:** Developer wishes to create context-specific form structure that depends on the query output.

#### Solution

- Create one or more sub-form with attached VBA that changes dependent on the query ouput.
- Connect the subform(s) to the primary form and load as needed depending on the context.

#### See also

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access+forms+vba
- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=msft+access+dynamic+subform
- [How to dynamically load, access and unload subforms in microsoft access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874299/how-to-dynamically-load-access-and-unload-subforms-in-microsoft-access)